# Is there a preset in Java to create toolboxes or is there an program for it?

Tags: java, editor, toolbox

I wanted to ask how one create a toolbox like in Word/Excel ... in Java.

I would do that by creating an popup where I would add all buttons on. But before I try to create one I was looking for a preset (especially where i find all the icons. Are they different Fonts or pictures?).

Is there an editor for it maybe? Maybe also in Eclipse like the `WindowBuilder` especially made for creating Toolboxes? Or do I have to create them my self.

For those who don't understand what I mean with Toolbox:

[image]

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: @Sascha I suggest making an Answer of your Comment, to resolve this Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque done.

Comment: @StephenC Do you know if there is a List of Icons where one can use them. So in Word there are Icons for Bold, New Comment, Formate Cells, and so on. Is there a side where one can download icons like this?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  Not in Java SE.  You could probably find icons from 3rd party vendors.  Google for it.  I saw some possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing has a [JToolBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html), but no "toolbox" component.

[image]

Comment: Ye I know this. Was just thinking if there maybe is a simpler way than craeting a popup